# In Web Audio API is it possible to randomly select from an array of samples for audio playback?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a webpage with about 100 samples, many of them different versions of the same sound; a simplified version with four samples is at http://stephenandrewtaylor.net/sample-array-test/sample-loader.html.

This page uses code from William Turner's excellent book Javascript for Sound Artists, loading all the samples into an object (starting with `var appSounds` - I've included Turner's code at the top).

```
// *** adapted from William Turner's "Javascript for Sound Artists" ***
"use strict";

var audioContext = new AudioContext();

function audioFileLoader(fileDirectory, callback) {
  var soundObj = {};
  var playSound = undefined;
  var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
  soundObj.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;
  getSound.open("GET", soundObj.fileDirectory, true); // 'true' argument enables asynchronous download
  getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  getSound.onload = function() {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) { // callback function
      soundObj.soundToPlay = buffer;  // stored as global variable
    });
};

  getSound.send(); // initiate the XMLHttpRequest

  soundObj.play = function(time, setStart, setDuration) {
    playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    playSound.buffer = soundObj.soundToPlay;
    playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime + time || audioContext.currentTime, setStart || 
      0, setDuration || soundObj.soundToPlay.duration);

  if (typeof callback === "function") {
    return callback(playSound);
    } else {
      return playSound.connect(audioContext.destination);
    }
  };

  soundObj.stop = function(time) {
    playSound.stop(audioContext.currentTime + time || audioContext.currentTime);
  };
  return soundObj;
}

function audioBatchLoader(obj) {
  var callback = undefined;
  var prop = undefined;
  for (prop in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[prop] === "function") {
      callback = obj[prop];
      delete obj[prop];
    }
  }
  for (prop in obj) {
    obj[prop] = audioFileLoader(obj[prop], callback);
  }
  return obj;
}

// *** here is the code I would like to improve if possible ***
var appSounds = {
  stringPluck0: "StringA4-0.mp3",
  stringPluck1: "StringA4-1.mp3",
  stringPluck2: "StringA4-2.mp3",
  stringPluck3: "StringA4-3.mp3",
// *** how to make this an array, like stringPluck[0] etc.? ***

  nodes: function nodeGraph(sound) {
   sound.connect(audioContext.destination);
  }
};

var sounds = audioBatchLoader(appSounds);

function playback() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
 switch (rand) {
  case 0: sounds.stringPluck0.play(); break;
  case 1: sounds.stringPluck1.play(); break;
  case 2: sounds.stringPluck2.play(); break;
  case 3: sounds.stringPluck3.play(); break;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", playback);
```

I would really like for this to be an array, within the object:

```
stringPluck: ["StringA4-0.mp3", "StringA4-1.mp3", 
  "StringA4-2.mp3", "StringA4-3.mp3"]
```

Then I could use a random number to trigger `stringPluck[rand]`. But I can't get it to work; I've looked at several examples here, and studied William Turner's book. What I have right now *is* working, but the code gets pretty verbose when you start loading in lots of samples.

If you're interested, the main project, using d3, is here:
http://stephenandrewtaylor.net/exo-sonification/exoplanets.html.

Comment: Your example code is missing some stuff, like how you get from stringPluck<n> to sound in the call to nodeGraph.  And it's not clear if you fetch and decode each mp3 file every time when you play it or if you do it just once.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking a look - I've added more code (adapted from William Turner) - I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the other guy's answer, the audioBatchLoader rewritten does the trick-- gotta make sure to return the whole object instead of just the stringPluck though :)

```
function audioBatchLoader(obj) {
    let callback = obj.nodes;
    let mp3;
    for (mp3 in obj.stringPluck) {
        obj.stringPluck[mp3] = audioFileLoader(obj.stringPluck[mp3], callback);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Cheers Professor!

(P.S. changing the "sounds.stringPluck.length" to "appSounds.stringPluck.length" like so reduces errors):

```
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * appSounds.stringPluck.length);
```

--Logan

Comment: Thanks so much Logan, this is fantastic! And thanks Raymond as well - I'm updating all my Web Audio projects. I also was able to load different banks of samples, as objects within objects, using "appSounds.sounds.othersounds.length", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work out all the details, but you could start with defining

`var appSounds = {
  stringPluck: ["StringA4-0.mp3", "StringA4-1.mp3", 
  "StringA4-2.mp3", "StringA4-3.mp3"];
  ...
};`

Then update `audioBatchLoader` to something like

`function audioBatchLoader(obj) {
  // Get the nodeGraph method
  let callback = obj.nodes;
  // Run through the stringPluck array and create a corresponding
  // soundObj for each element.
  return obj.stringPluck.map(mp3 => {
    audioFileLoader(mp3, callback);
  });
}`

Then you can do, I think,

`function playback() {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
  sounds[rand].play();
}`

I didn't test this, though.

Comment: Thanks for this! When I try this code I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined at playback" for the line "sounds[rand].play()." I tried both "sounds[rand].play" and sounds.stringPluck[rand].play" - do you know why this would happen?

Comment: I didn't actually test this code, so I don't know. It was just a sketch on how you might do this.  You'll have to debug it or write something else.  Maybe inspect what sound[0] is?  That's probably a good hint to figure out what's wrong.